# Spring MVC putting values into XML Config file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working a Spring MVC project and in my Service object I need some information like system password, id, url etc but I would like to put this into one of the XML files so it can be changes without changing code.. which XML should I put it in and how do I read it into the object

Answer (score 4):

Moving constants to XML is a first step, but to make your application truly configurable you should use external `.properties` file:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///foo/bar/conf.properties" />
```

And then use it everywhere in your XML configuration:

```
<property name="password" value="${db_password}"/>
```

Where `conf.properties` contains:

```
db_password=secret
```

Note that you can also place properties file inside WAR (with `location="classpath:/foo/bar/conf.properties"`).

If you are a happy user of Spring 3.1 (currently RC2) you can take advantage of new [`@PropertySource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)annotation:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/myco/app.properties")
```

Comment: It's usually best practice to put your properties file on the classpath and include it with `location="classpath:conf.properties"`.

Comment: @jiggy: yep, I added that in the meantime, but thanks for pointing it out.